# Convert .doc to .docx in c# / vb.net

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, vb.net-2010

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document mDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

*//This function will convert .doc to .docx
    Public Function FileSave(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal openPWD As String, ByVal savePWD As String)    
                mDocument.SaveAs2(fileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument, , openPWD, , savePWD)             
                End Function*
```

Above function has written to convert .doc file to .docx using word interop.
file is created succeessfully but when open the file contents is missing.

Is missing something or is there any alternate method to convert .doc to .docx in c# or Vb.net

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document mDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();` this line creates a fresh new document which is empty as it is newly created. You need to open your own file.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be creating a brand new Word document in memory and then saving that as .DOCX which is why the output file is empty.

```
// This line just creates a brand new empty document
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document mDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
```

You need to open the existing document first and then SaveAs your desired file type.

Something like this (haven't tested it myself as not on a machine with Interop)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document mDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(sourcepath);
mDocument.SaveAs(outputpath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument);
```

**At OPs request, how to get an instance of Word**

```
// Create Word object
Word._Application wordApp = null;

// Try and get an existing instance
try
{
    wordApp = (Word._Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
}
catch { /* Ignore error */ }

// Check if we got an instance, if not then create one
if (wordApp == null)
{
    wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
}

//Now you can use wordApp
... wordApp.Documents.Open(...);
```

Comment: where is the object defined wordApp

Comment: Sorry, assumed you'd have one. I've added the code to get a Word instance.

Comment: @NKD Actually, the correct command to create a NEW document in the Word application is : wordApp.Documents.ADD(). The NEW keyword is not supported by Word in the manner a .NET developer expects and should be used only for Word.Application. For all objects running within the application, use an ADD method.